# How to write integration test using capybara for rails 2.3.11?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, integration-testing, capybara

Hi friends I am writing integration test for Rails 2.3.11 application.I have found many tutorials for

```
Rails 3
RSpec 2
Capybara 1.1.2
```

http://railscasts.com/episodes/257-request-specs-and-capybara

http://techiferous.com/2010/04/using-capybara-in-rails-3/

But my Rails application is 2.3.11.

I am using

```
Rails 2.3.11
RSpec 1.3.0
Capybara 0.3.9
```

Guide me in right direction.

Comment: Did you try these tutorials and encounter any problems with your older rails?

Comment: yes.adding require 'capybara/rspec' in spec/spec_helper.rb results Missing Source file no such file to load 'capybara/rspec' error.

Comment: Have you a Gemfile in your Rails 2 application ? Have you add capybara gem ?

Comment: I have found good tutorial to use rspec 1.x with capybara here  http://codingfrontier.com/integration-testing-setup-with-rspec-and-capy